# Low bias voltage from headphone jack

Tags: microphone

I want to connect my microphone capsule (JLI2555) to a headphone jack. I need a voltage to power the capsule from the microphone pin of the headphone jack cable but when I measure it with a voltmeter it reads 1 mV. When I connect the cable to a phone I read 0.7 V. In both cases not enough to bias the microphone with my JFET.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What device is this headphone jack on?

Comment: On a laptop and once i tried on a phone

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're using the right plug, probably a 3.5mm TRRS plug.  Then measure the voltage between the different contacts.  There is no one standard for wiring these plugs, and phones and laptops may be different.

For a laptop, it may well be:

- tip: left audio
- ring 1: right audio
- ring 2: ground
- sleeve: microphone

The power to the microphone will be current limited.

Comment: Yeah I know all of this. Still the readings are as mentioned